# Mustache render with json escapes

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have simply template.

```
let t="{\"CName\":\"{{Value}}\"}";
```

Source object is:

```
let obj={"value":"\"JSC inc\""};
```

After render `Mustache.render(t,obj)` has string with html escapes

```
"{"CName":"&quot;JSC inc&quot;"}"
```

How is a best and easy way to get rendered string with json escapes - `"{"CName":"\"JSC inc\""}"`

Answer (score 0):

The answer really will depends on which mustache implementation you're using.

But in common implementation, you'd use either of those syntax to bypass HTML escaping:

1. `{{{ Value }}}`
2. `{{& Value}}`

Comment: Thx, but it's not good. It is unescapes and after render do not parse result to json correctly.

Comment: @MihalBy Mustache wasn't build to generate valid JSON. My suggestion would be to JSON escape the values before passing them to Mustache.

Comment: Sory, if you use unescapes rendered string is `{"CName":""JSC inc""}` - without any escapes.

Comment: `let obj={"value":"\"JSC inc\""};` would need to become `let obj={"value":"\\"JSC inc\\""}; (note the double `\\`)
`

Comment: I think with double slashes render work clear. But i can't modify each time all fields of source object.

Comment: Then I don't think Mustache is the right solution for you. Since it's JSON, how about just formatting this in your code and rely on JS's JSON parsers? Or maybe checkout [SelectTransform](https://selecttransform.github.io/site/)